# I want to get a String return type for a http response i get for http post request i trigger

Tags: java

I want to get a String return type for a http response I get for http post request i trigger, but my return variable is giving error

> "message cannot be resolved to a variable"

Subsequently I have to convert that return string value to a json string data.

here is my code....

```
public String sendPOST(String _postData) {

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(POST_URL);
    httpPost.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(_postData, HTTP.UTF_8);
    entity.setContentType("application/json");
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse;
    try {
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        System.out.println("POST Response Status:: " + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);

            String message = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(reader);
            String type = message.getClass().getName();

            System.out.println(type);
            System.out.println("Final : " + message);
        }
        reader.close();

        // print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        httpClient.close();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return message;
  }
```

Comment: The error (and stacktrace) is happening on which line?

Comment: what is the status code... like is it _500 internal server error_? then we could need the server side implementation...

Comment: Sorry about the lack of detailed information, it was a compiler error , now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Because local "message" variable you are using outside of loop. Add global "message" variable, That should solve your problem.